# How to add an extra checkbox to a messagebox in tkinter?

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter, tk-toolkit

I cannot resolve the following problem for ages. How to add an extra checkbox to a standard message box in Tkinter?

I watched many different videos on youtube on how to create a custom message box with tk.Toplevel, however, it works differently than a classic message box.

Basically, what I need to get is to add a checkbox like "don't ask me again" for a specific warning message. I don't believe that I need to go with the whole new message box just because of a little checkbox.

[Checkbox that I want to have](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5WJht.png)

Custom checkbox with TopLevel does not work properly for me. It does not pause the program (in my case, the message box pops up inside of the while loop and, depending on the response, should either break the loop or continue the execution). With the toplevel widget it just throws numerous message boxes without pausing.

I hope someone will be able to help me.

Comment: create a custom one using `Toplevel` widget

Comment: Yes, the `Toplevel` way of doing things is best, because you can customize the widgets. You can still make a `Toplevel` return which button was pressed, just like the `messagebox` does.

Comment: There are techniques for a popup causing the program to wait for the popup to be dismissed. Research `wait_window`.

Comment: @BryanOakley could he subclass tkinter.messagebox ??

Comment: @pippo1980 This was my initial idea, however modifying the default library looks complicated and dangerous to me. It seems that I have to create my own messageboxes

Comment: See here: http://www.java2s.com/Code/Python/GUI-Tk/AddacheckboxtoaDialog.htm add checkbox to Dialog (message box is a subclass of Dialog)